# Cancel javascript redirection on mouse click event

Tags: javascript, redirect

I want to cancel a redirection started by a javascript function. 
The javascript redirects to the home page in 5 seconds and it appears as an error message. I want to make the redirection to be cancelled on a mouse click on the error message. Any help please.

[image]

PHP Code:

```
<div id="error">    
<?php
    //redirect
    if (isset($_GET['err'])){
        if ($_GET['err'] == 1){
            echo "You are successfully logged out. You will be redirected to the home page in <strong><span id = 'seconds'> 5 </span> </strong> seconds.";
        }elseif($_GET['err'] == 0){
            echo "Your session has been expired. Please login again.!";
        }
    }
?>  
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
        <script>
        var seconds = 5;
        var err = <?php echo $_GET['err'] ; ?>;

        if (err == 1){
            setInterval(
            function(){
                if (seconds <= 1) {
                    window.location = 'http://****.***.***.***/***';
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = --seconds;
                }
                },
                1000
            );
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where do you handle your *click* event? Have you even tried to handle it?

Comment: Hint: You'll have to clear the interval with `clearInterval` in another function. For this you'll need a reference to the original interval `var myRedirectionInterval = setInterval(....)`.

Comment: you want to cancel on clickin on error message, but I don't see anywhere in your code where you show the error message so the user can click it..

Comment: I've used jquery to fade out the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually trying to stop a setInterval, which you can easily do by naming it first and then clearing it in the condition you want.

```
var redirInt = setInterval(function() {
    // etc.
},5000);
```

and your cancelling line…

```
clearInterval(redirInt);
```

Comment: Thanks inhan. It works like a charm. Also thanks a lot for all of you who tried to help me.

Comment: No problem. And in cases you're using the `setTimeout()` function (a one-time-only version of setInterval) you will need to use the `clearTimeout()` function instead. To be able to manipulate any interval function you will need to name it regardless if it's setInterval or setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

```
var tId; // create a global var (or put it in a managed scope)
$(function() { // jquery onload
  tId = setInterval(function() { ... },5000); // or use timeout if no counter
  $("#errordiv").on("click",function() { 
    clearInterval(tId); // clear it
 });
});
```

Comment: No explanation, not suitable for the current case :(. Edit: and suddenly jQuery.

Comment: Yes - I saw the jquery comment:)

Comment: Woops, forget the additional jQuery comment, I skimmed OP's comment ^^".

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` returns the ID of the timer that it creates so that you can cancel it using `clearInterval`.

You could use something like this:

```
var timer;

$(document).ready(function() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {...}, 1000);

    $('#error').click(function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```

Comment: He also provides a countdown in his example, so `setInterval` seems reasonable in this case.

Comment: @Zeta: I seemed to have skimmed over that part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

    var seconds = 5;
    var err = <?php echo $_GET['err'] ; ?>;
    var redir = null;

    if (err == 1){

        var redir_interval = setInterval(
        function(){
            if (seconds <= 1) {
                redir = window.location = 'http://****.***.***.***/***';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = --seconds;
            }
            },
            1000
        );
    }

    function cancel_redir() {

        redir = null;
        clearInterval(redir_interval);

    }

</script>

<div id="error" onclick="cancel_redir();">
You are successfully logged out. You will be redirected to the home page in <strong><span id = 'seconds'> 5 </span> </strong> seconds.
</div>
```